# Extension problem when convert pdf to png using Imagemagick

Tags: php

I try to convert pdf file (5 pages) with imagemagick. I can convert it but i get a weird extension.

Example:
fax.png.0,
fax.png.1,
fax.png.2,
fax.png.3,
fax.png.4

This is the command that i use:

```
convert -density 140 /var/www/html/ok/fax.pdf  -resize 25% -quality 100 -colors 256 /var/www/html/ok/fax.png
```

How to fix it so it will become only fax0.png, fax1.png, fax2.png, fax3.png, fax4.png

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try convert -density 140 /var/www/html/ok/fax.pdf -resize 25% -quality 100 -colors 256 /var/www/html/ok/fax%1d.png

Comment: hi i try the code but still have the same problem

Comment: @ajreal thank you for your help. your code lead me to correct solution. your code the problem only typo error at 1d.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#save_escapes

Answer (score 1):

I assume since you tagged this with php that you're using PHP, and not just imagemagick at the command line.

If so, use `rename` to change the file names as desired:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Answer (score 1):

the solution for this problem is add the %d after the filename:

```
convert -density 140 /var/www/html/ok/fax.pdf  -resize 25% -quality 100 -colors 256 /var/www/html/ok/fax%d.png
```

read more here:

[Filename Percent Escapes](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#save_escapes)

Answer (score 1):

I dont know, if this still helps you. But I had similar weird problems. I solved it, by simply deaktivating the alpha channel like this:

```
convert -alpha off -density 300 -quality 85 -... old.pdf new.tif
```